# How to compare two data frames and extract data effectivily in R

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

I want to compare two data frames, but they are long, and the code I have now takes more than an hour to run. This years data are going to be compared to last years data, and if it is a match, it is placed in an Approve-data frame. How can I do this more effectively?

The dataframes have more than 20 000 rows in them...

```
p = 1                                                                 
k = Start
l = Stop
for(i in 1:nrow(NewData))
{
  Year = substrYear(NewData, i)
  Month = substrMonth(NewData, i)
  Day = substrDay(NewData, i)
  y = NewData$Time[i]
  z = NewData$B[i]
  w = NewData$C[i]
  for(j in k:l)
  { 
    if ( Year == as.numeric(substrYear(OldData, j)) + 1
         & Month == substrMonth(OldData, j)
         & Day == substrDag(OldData, j)
         & y == OldData$Time[j]
         & z == OldData$B[j]
         & w == OldData$C[j])
    {  

      ANewData[p,] = NewData[i,] # Approved
      AOldData[p,] = OldData[j,] # Approved
      p = p+1 
      next

    }
  }
}
```

I get data from Excel. This part is OK. When it comes into R, I have structured it.

This is part of the historic Excel file. The new data is similar.

```
Date        Time    Station         Place       Klass       Cars    
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-1     Big     1   
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-1     Small       30  
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-2     Unknown     2   
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-2     Big     1   
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-2     Small       35  
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-1-E6    Unknown     4   
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-1-E6    Big     18  
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-1-E6    Small       160 
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-2-E6    Unknown     2   
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-2-E6    Big     4
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-2-E6    Small       165
```

These are transformed to this, coding them as dataframes.

```
Date        Time    Station         Place       Small   Big Unknown
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-1     30  1   0
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-2     35  1   2
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-1-E6    160 18  4
01/05/2013  00:00   Klett - E6, S-snitt KLE-2-E6    165 4   2
```

Then I want to compare the two dataframes, by date, time, station and place. If it is a match, the values for `OldData` are placed in `AOldData` and the values for `NewData` are placed in `ANewData`.

From here I'm going to sum `Small`, `Big` and`Unknown` values in each matrix (or dataframe) for Station and place. I thought of using `ddply`.

Comment: Could you pleas poste the first rows of your data.frame so that we get an idea of the structure of your data.frame? Are you talking about an actual `data.frame` object in R or do you still have to read it from a text file?

Comment: In addition to adding two _minimal_ input data frames (5, 10, 20-ish rows?) to your question, provide the desired output. Also describe more thoroughly _in words_ what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Seems you'd be a lot better off turning your dates into the numeric equivalents instead of a zillion `substr*` calls.

Comment: What part of `Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt KLETT-1` is `Station` and what part is `Place`?

Comment: Klett-1 is Place,
Klett - Rv.707, S-snitt is Station.

I see those didn't come out as they should have... As a rule, the last 7 characters between time and the numerics, are Place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am late ;-)

Hard to answer without having the data...

If the number and order of rows and columns of the old and new data.frame do match exactly:

You could try to extract the columns that shall be compared from the old and new data.frame into two new data frames (that contain only the columns that shall be equal!)

Then simply compare them:

```
diff <- old.data.frame == new.data.frame # creates a data.frame of TRUE/FALSE for each "cell"; I guess you called these data.frames "AOldData" and "ANewData" in your question above
colSums( diff ) # shows you the number of matches per column (TRUE = match = equal)
```

If the number and order of rows and columns of the old and new data.frame do NOT match exactly:

Match the corresponding rows via a "join" (merge command or sqldf package with a SQL query) and compare the resulting data.frame like above (e. g. by splitting the columns into two data.frames).